# Question about the boundary of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f =\chi_A$ be the characteristic function of $A$, that is: this function $f(x)$ is $1$ when $x \in A$ and $0$ when $x \notin A$. Does it follow that the boundary of the set $\partial A = \{ x : f(x) \; \text{is discontinuous} \} $ ?

It seems obvious if we consider for instance sets in the line, but I cannot see why. Maybe there is a counter-example? Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in \mathring A$ then $f$ is constantly $1$ in a neighbourhood of $x$, hence $f$ is continous at $x$.
If $x\in(\overline A)^c$ then $f$ is constantly $0$ in a neighbourhood of $x$, hence $f$ is continuous at $x$.
For all remaining $x$, that is $x\in \partial A$, every punctured neighbourhood of $x$ has points from $A$ as well as from $A^c$, i.e. points with values $0$ and points with value $1$; hence $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

Comment: what is $ \mathring A$  ?

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a point such that there exist two sequences $\{x_n\}_n$ and $\{y_n\}_n$ with $x_n \to x$, $y_n \to x$, $x_n \in A$, $y_n \notin A$, then $\lim_n f(x_n) = \lim_n 1=1$ while $\lim_n f(y_n) = \lim_n 0 =0$. Hence $f$ is discontinuous at $x$.

Viceversa, if there exist two sequences $\{x_n\}_n$ and $\{y_n\}_n$ with $x_n \to x$, $y_n \to x$ but $\lim_n f(x_n) \neq \lim_n f(y_n)$, then we can assume that $\lim_n f(x_n)=1$ and $\lim_n f(y_n) =0$. Hence, definitely, $x_n \in A$ and $y_n \notin A$, showing that $x \in \partial A$.

Comment: what definition of boundary are you using ?

Comment: The boundary of $S \subset X$ is the set of points $p$ of $X$ such that every neighborhood of $p$ contains at least one point of $S$ and at least one point not of $S$.